# How can I include template tags in static files in Django?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I would like to be able to DRY out my static files by using a template tag, like `{% url 'my_view' %}`, in my static file, instead of `/path/to/my_view`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Static files aren't served by django, so no. Is it for js files?

Comment: @danielcorreia Yes. They’re JS. I meant something that would run when I used `python manage.py collectstatic` (I don’t plan to change the URLs more often then I change the JS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no. But you can circumvent this, there's two approaches I can think of:

1. add a script with the urls you need in your base html template, they need to be available globally so that you can access them with other scripts
2. make a script to generate a .js file with all your urls and place it with all the other staticfiles ([django translations for js](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code) use a similar approach)

Approach 1, would be something like:

```
<html>
...
<script>
  var myApp = {
    URLS: {
      login: {% url 'login' %},
      welcome: {% url 'welcome' %},
      ...
    }
  }
</script>
<script>console.log("The login url is " + myApp.URLS.login + "!")</script>
<script src="script/that/uses/urls.js"></script>
...
</html>
```