# Loading static file to a css file django-python

Tags: python, css, django, heroku, static

I have a css file and I want to link another static file to it.How can I accomplish this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'tinymce-mobile';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("fonts/tinymce-mobile.woff?8x92w3") format("woff"); 
}
```

how can I load this "font/static-mobile.woff"

Both {% load static %} and {% load staticfiles%} are not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I include template tags in static files in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373493/how-can-i-include-template-tags-in-static-files-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Template filters and tags only work in HTML files that are rendered in Django views. In static files (CSS, JS etc.) you have to use hard-coded absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your     settings.py file there you will see    STATIC_URL = '/static/' under it create a     STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
The STATICFILES_DIRS tuple tells Django where to look for static files and also  we must tell Django to also look for static files in a folder called static in our root directory

OR

Django also provides a mechanism for collecting static files into one place so that they can be served easily. Using the    collectstatic command before using the     collectstatic command create a     STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')  Django looks for all static files in your apps and collects them through the STATIC_ROOT. So when we run     python manage.py collectstatic, gather all static files into a folder called staticfiles in our project root directory.